# Microsoft Graph Filter Applications by Owner

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to find all the Azure Active Directory Applications owned by a specific user/application.

So for example, I want to know all the applications owned by `fulano.de.tal@mydomain.com`.

I tried this:

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications?`$filter=owners/address eq 'fulano.de.tal@mydomain.com'"
```

But that gives the following error:

> The parent value for a property access of a property 'address' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.

I understand this to mean that `owners` is a list, so I can't filter off a child of one of the objects in that list.

Is there any way to filter for a specific owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD Application and added owner** as below:

[image]

**To fetch the applications owned by a specific user**, use the below query:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/ownedObjects/microsoft.graph.application?$select=displayName,id
```

[image]

```json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#applications(displayName,id)",
"value": [
{
"displayName": "testruk",
"id": "8a49d882-b871-4969-b727-xxxxxx"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!  `ownedObjects` was what I was missing!  Thank you!